# Python не видет мой ввод.Ниже код. В результате выдает только а. А если же сделать явное преобразование b в int, то вовсе выдает ошибку. Типо b = ""

Tags: python, input

```
a = input()
b = input()
print(a + b)
```

Comment: В онлайн компиляторе все работает, может проблема в самом PyCharm?

Comment: Обновите PyCharm или включите эмуляцию терминала в консоли PyCharm.

Comment: Спасибо, обновление помогло. Интересна конечно причина возникновения такой банальной ошибки...

Comment: Не думаю, что это банальная ошибка